# How can I convert an Excel file to CSV with Perl's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel?

Tags: perl, export-to-csv, import-from-excel

I have an Excel sheet and am able to convert it into *.csv* format using Perl. My only problem is that some of my data in the Excel sheet cells contain commas and that 
has to be retained in the CSV format also, but while converting it takes as a 
seperator. How can I retreive the data in the cell with commas as it is and print it in 
the CSV?

For example, in the Excel sheet `A1` cell contains the data `{0xAAAA,0xFFFF,0xAAAA,0xAAAA}` I want the same data with commas in the `A1` cell in CSV file also. I am [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel).

Comment: show some sample input. show how your output will look up. A picture speaks a 1000 words.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.15/lib/Text/CSV.pm) for parsing and creating your csv files.
Be more specific if you do not know how to use the module for your task.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the commas in your fields to be interpreted as separators, enclose your fields with characters like double quotes:

`"10","10,00","156"`

Comment: If you enclose your fields with "", you also have to escape the double quotes in the value.